# Object differ doesn't detect changes

Tags: java, object

I'm using [java-object-diff](https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff) to get differences between two objects, and it works nice until it have to check Lists or Objects. My method looks like:

```
public <T, G> T findDifferences(T base, G updated) {
  try {
    Class<T> tClass = (Class<T>) base.getClass();
    Object diffObj = tClass.newInstance();
    DiffNode diff = ObjectDifferBuilder.buildDefault().compare(base, updated);
    diff.visit((node, visit) -> {
      if (node.hasChanges() && !node.hasChildren()) {
        try {
          node.canonicalSet(diffObj, node.canonicalGet(updated));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Error while getting canonicalGet");
        }
      }
    });
    if (!diff.getState().name().equals("UNTOUCHED")) {
      return tClass.cast(diffObj);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error while finding differences");
    return null;
  }
}
```

The problem is here:

```
"allergens": [
        "allergens"
    ],
    "ingredients": [
        "ingredients"
    ],
    "modules": [
        {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "Module name",
            "airline": null,
            "blockTime": {
                "from": "08:28:16.415",
                "to": "00:00:00"
            },
            "flightTime": {
                "from": "08:27:20.704",
                "to": "00:00:00"
            },
            "fares": null
        }
```

If i want to update the object and send e.g.

```
{
"allergens": ["ABC"]}
```

it's not finding the differences. Similar problem is with objects, like "modules".

Comment: How are you calling the method and how do you save your old/new Objects/Lists to later compare them? It sounds like you are probably doung something like `Object newObject = object;` and then checking for the difference between `newObject` and `object` later.

Comment: Comparing objects is here -> DiffNode diff = ObjectDifferBuilder.buildDefault().compare(base, updated);
and saving differences here -> node.canonicalSet(diffObj, node.canonicalGet(updated));
As i told, it works for single objects (like String).